# How to create a public key and private key using web3js?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I am learning to use web3js in this case to create an ethereum address and a private key to make a simple dapp.

Can anyone tell me to use this web3js?

My achievement recently studied to see the balance of ethereum and token ERC20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
  } else {
    // Set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io"))
  }

  console.log(web3.eth.accounts.create())
</script>
```

You'll get

```
{
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respon. Did that work? because before I used it. This error is found in the absence of function in the program.